# Unable to filter logstreams for boto3 logs of aws lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I am unable to filter out **logStreams** for **lambda** function using **boto3** API, with `'endtime'` filter or `'logStreamNamePrefix'` filter.

***This works:***

```
client = boto3.client('logs',
                      aws_access_key_id=aws_account['access_key'],
                      aws_secret_access_key=aws_account['secret_key'],
                      region_name=region)
logGroupName = '/aws/lambda/' + function_name
response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    startTime=int((datetime(2020, 1, 15)- datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()),   # epoch_time        
)
```

***But these don`t:***

1.

```
response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    startTime=int((datetime(2020, 1, 15)- datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()),   # epoch_time    
    endTime=int((datetime(2020, 1, 31)- datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds())       
)
```

> ERROR: Empty list is returned, although log data is there for the
>   specified time range

2.

```
response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    startTime=int((datetime(2020, 1, 15)- datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()),   # epoch_time    
    logStreamNamePrefix='^2020/01'  # logs starting with this prefix        
)
```

> ERROR:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "logStreamNamePrefix", must be one of: logGroupName, logStreamNames, startTime, endTime, filterPattern, nextToken, limit, interleaved
```

Answer (score 1):

As a temporary fix, I am polling all the responses and then filtering it expilictly.

```
response = client.filter_log_events(
    logGroupName=logGroupName,
    startTime=int((datetime(2020, 1, 15)- datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()),   # epoch_time
)

filtered_response = list(filter(lambda x: x['logStreamName'].startswith('2020/01'), response['events']))
```